# How to create a css animation that scrolls an element horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a React project that has a banner that should be automatically scrolled horizontally. I could reach the animation with the following:

```
  "@keyframes marquee": {
    "0%": { transform: "translateX(0);" },
    "100%": { transform: "translateX(-100%);" },
  },
```

The problem is that the user should be able to hover the banner and scroll the it manually. I could create the manual scrolling with the following:

```
pingsSectionRef.current.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const scrollAmount = 10;
  if (pingsSectionRef.current)
    pingsSectionRef.current.scrollLeft +=
      event.deltaY > 0 ? scrollAmount : -scrollAmount;
});
```

The problem is that the scrolling works only to the right direction, but content that left the screen never appears anymore on manual scrolling (I guess because of the translateX animation). How to make it possible to scroll both directions?

Comment: Scroll it with JavaScript only, not CSS - what CSS is doing is not scrolling, it just looks like scrolling.

Comment: @vrugtehagel it solved, fixed using strollTo() instead of scrolling through css

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you have an auto-animation using CSS, and you are adding a "wheel event" to control it.

Here are my suggestions:

1. Do it the "[react way](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#wheelevent-handler)": Instead of manually adding an event listener, try to handle the state programmatically.
2. You could add or remove a class to play or pause the auto-scroll animation.
3. If you need more granular control, you could use an animation library like [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/).

Here's an example of how you could implement it:

```
const Banner = ({ images }) => {
  const [isAutoScroll, setIsAutoScroll] = useState(true);

  const onHoverHandler = () => setIsAutoScroll(false);
  const onBlurHandler = () => setIsAutoScroll(true);

  return (
    <div
      className="container"
      onMouseEnter={onHoverHandler}
      onMouseLeave={onBlurHandler}
    >
      <div className={`scrolleable ${isAutoScroll ? "play" : "pause"}`}>
        {images.length > 0 &&
          images.map((img) => {
            return <ImageBanner key={img}> {img} </ImageBanner>;
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And for the CSS:

```css
.scrolleable {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: marquee;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.play {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
.pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

You would need to adjust this idea for your specific stack (e.g. CSS loaders) or use case.

Another possible solution is to not rely on CSS and handle the position of the marquee element by changing the property `scrollLeft` programmatically. You might need to use `useLayoutEffect` and a cleanup function to avoid any memory leaks. In this case, your component would have to deal with incrementing or decrementing the position at every possible touchpoint (scrolling left, scrolling right, auto-scroll when the mouse is out of the element).